# In MATLAB, extract row indices from a larger matrix which contains all row elements of a 4*3 matrix

Tags: matlab

For example,

```
A=[1 0 1; 1 0 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 0];
B=[0 0 0; 0 0 1; 0 1 0; 0 1 1; 1 0 0; 1 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 1 1];
```

All I want is to find row indices of `B` containing entire rows of `A`.

Comment: So for example column 3 of B contains column 3 of A? And the result would be just index 3? I mean, is _order_ of elements important? Also, would it be fine if column j of B contains column i of A with i different from j? Are all elements always 0 and 1?

Comment: No, order is not important.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Please clarify my other questions

Comment: Can you add the desired output of your example?

Comment: I just edited the column to row.we need to find row numbers.As for above example output would be [6 5 8 1].                             Row containing 1 0 1, 1 0 0, 1 1 1, 0 0 0 occur at row numbers 6,5,8,1 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** here -

```
index = find(any(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(B,[3 2 1])),2),1))
```

Or use **[`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)** with `'rows'` option -

```
[~,~,index] = intersect(A, B, 'rows')
```

Or -

```
[~,index] = intersect(B, A, 'rows')
```

Or **[`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)** with `'rows'` (maybe a bit complicated) -

```
[~,rem_index] = setdiff(B,A,'rows');
index = setdiff(1:size(B,1),rem_index)
```

---

**Edit:** If the order is important, you can modify the earlier codes like these -

```
[index,~] = find(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(B,[3 2 1])),2)).')
```

Or -

```
[~,~,index] = intersect(A, B, 'rows','stable')
```

Comment: @LuisMendo You got mine too! Hope OP is looking for something like these! Initial reaction was that, it was a bit complicated.

Comment: thank you @ LuisMendo and @ divakar. Both solutions are working fine.

Comment: What if the order does matter @LuisMendo ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option:

```
index = find(ismember(B, A, 'rows'));
```

You can also apply [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html):

```
index = find(any(pdist2(A,B)==0, 1));
```